# create dynamically a table in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to create a table by javascript. It should be a Appointment calender for events. with two rows and two lines per event. In the first line are the datenumber and the kind of event. In the second line are the weekday and the place, where the event are. For the Phase of Development I have only an exemple text. I include my js-file in my html-file but there isn't a table. Can someone check my code because I did not find a mistake

```js
function dates(){
var test = 31;
var rows = 2;

var text_bsp = "example";


var tab = document.createElement("table");
var line1 = document.createElement("tr");
var line2 = document.createElement("tr");
var cell_date = document.createElement("td");
var cell_event = document.createElement("td");
var cell_day = document.createElement("td");
var cell_place = document.createElement("td");


var ausgabe = document.getElementById('content-container');

ausgabe.appendChild(tab);

for(var i=1;i < 32; i++)
{
    tab.appendChild(line1);

    for(var j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
    line1.appendChild(cell_date);
    cell_date.createTextNode(text_bsp);
    line1.appendChild(cell_event);
    cell_event.createTextNode(text_bsp);
    }

     tab.appendChild(line2);

     for(var k=0;j<3;k++){
     line2.appendChild(cell_date);
     cell_date.createTextNode(text_bsp);
     line2.appendChild(cell_place);
     cell_place.createTextNode(text_bsp);
     }
}
}
```

I expected a table with 62 lines and 2 rows with the content 'example' in each cell.. But it dont work

Answer (score 0):

If you call `appendChild` onto a Node that is already part of the DOM, it gets removed from its previous location and moved to the new one. You either have to clone before appending:

```
line1.appendChild(cell_date.cloneNode(true));
```

or just create new nodes inside of the loops.

Answer (score 0):

There are are few changes required to achieve what you require. First, you'll need to move you row and cell creation inside the loop - currently you're creating one set of rows outside of the loop, before it begins.

Note also that you can't re-use the same row element, or cell element in the table to generate a table with multiple rows and cells - you need to create new element instances to achieve this.

Also consider using the `insertRow()`, `insertCell()` and `document.createTextNode()` methods as shown below:

```js
function dates() {
  var test = 31;
  var rows = 2;

  var text_bsp = "example";


  var tab = document.createElement("table");
  var ausgabe = document.getElementById('content-container');

  ausgabe.appendChild(tab);

  for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {

    /* 
    Create line1 row inside of for loop, to produce
    a new line for each iteration
    */
    var line1 = tab.insertRow(line1);

    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      /*
      Create new cell_date and cell_event cells for
      the current row we're creating
      */
      var cell_date = line1.insertCell();
      var cell_event = line1.insertCell();
      
      /*
      Create new text nodes for each cell via document
      and append these to respective cell elements
      */
      cell_date.append(document.createTextNode(text_bsp));
      cell_event.append(document.createTextNode(text_bsp));
    }

    /* 
    As before, create line2 row inside of for loop
    */
    var line2 = tab.insertRow();

    for (var k = 0; j < 3; k++) {
      var cell_date = line2.insertCell();
      var cell_place = line2.insertCell();
      
      cell_date.append(document.createTextNode(text_bsp));
      cell_place.append(document.createTextNode(text_bsp));
    }
  }
}

dates();
```

```html
<div id="content-container"></div>
```